# Unable to override Helper Class in Magento2

Tags: magento2, overrides, helper

I have used below code to override helper class.

**Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
 <preference for="Magento\CatalogInventory\Helper\Stock" type="Vendor\Module\Helper\Stock" />
</config>
```

Then **Vendor\Module\Helper\Stock.php**

```
<?php   
namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;  
class Stock extends \Magento\CatalogInventory\Helper\Stock
{

public function addIsInStockFilterToCollection($collection)
{
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')
                              ->registry('current_category');//get current category
     $categoryId = $category->getId(); 
     $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/testlog.log');
     $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
     $logger->addWriter($writer);       
    $logger->info('Category Id: '.$categoryId); 
    $parentCategoryId =  $category->getParentCategory()->getId();
    if(!is_null($category))
    {
        $stockFlag = 'has_stock_status_filter';

        if (!$collection->hasFlag($stockFlag)) {
            $isShowOutOfStock = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
                \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Configuration::XML_PATH_SHOW_OUT_OF_STOCK,
                \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
            );
            $resource = $this->getStockStatusResource();
            /* $resource->addStockDataToCollection(
                $collection,
                !$isShowOutOfStock
            ); */
            if($categoryId == 108 || $parentCategoryId == 108)
            {
               //show display out of stock products for particular category
               $resource->addStockDataToCollection(
                    $collection,
                    false
                );
            }else{
                $resource->addStockDataToCollection(
                    $collection,
                    $isShowOutOfStock
                );
            }
            $collection->setFlag($stockFlag, true);
        }

      }
   }
}
```

This is not overriding the mentioned helper class, Can anyone help me where i am wrong in the above code please. Thanks!!

Comment: Have you try bt clear the cache and deploy command again?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya, yes still its same not overrided

Comment: Paste all module files... Maybe your module is not well registered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the code you have highlighted looks looks OK. Make sure that your module.xml file is declaring Magento_CatalogInventory as a dependancy.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" >
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_CatalogInventory"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

If you hadn't already done this you may need to run `magento setup:upgrade --keep-generated` to update the module sequence in `config.php`. Also make sure you have run `bin/magento setup:di:compile` or deleted the `generated` directory.

Comment: This was the issue, Now the file is overriding.

Answer (score 0):

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <preference for="Magento\CatalogInventory\Helper\Stock" type="Vendor\Module\Helper\Magento\CatalogInventory\Stock" />

</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Helper/Magento/CatalogInventory/Stock.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Helper\Magento\CatalogInventory;


class Stock extends \Magento\CatalogInventory\Helper\Stock
{
    public function addIsInStockFilterToCollection($collection)
    {
        // your code
    }

}
```

I have added only di.xml and Helper class file code. I assume other files which is necessary for module is created properly.

Please let me know still if you have any issue.

Comment: hi, yes i have also used same thing here, u just added some other directories

Comment: In your function addIsInStockFilterToCollection remove all code and just add echo "hello"; die; and check your helper file is called or not